# iOS subscriptions: Why get subscriptions in sandbox stuck in is_in_billing_retry_period?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I am working on implementing iOS subscriptions. If a new subscription is purchased for a new test user in most cases the subscription will be renewed 5 times and is than canceled.

However, in some cases the subscription moves to `is_in_billing_retry_period = true` after the initial purchase and is stuck in this state forever.

I know that `is_in_billing_retry_period` is used to implement a grace period and than in production Apple will try to recover the the subscription (e.g. solve any billing issues) and it is great that this use case can be tested.

BUT is there any logic on which purchases will renew and which will get stuck in `is_in_billing_retry_period`? Or is this a random behaviour?

It is quite hard to test special use cases if one cannot specify which use case will be performed next by the sandbox...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're seeing the same thing with IAP